# Efficient row comparison in pandas dataframe on incomplete data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, vectorization

I work on an incomplete data that also has doubles and I need to clear it from doubles, choosing complete rows if available.

For example: [that's how the data look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJuqS.jpg)

I need to search trough each row to see whether it's a double (has a 'rank'>1), and whether if it is incomplete itself, but has some complete doubles.
I'll explain now:

- not every row with the 'rank' = 1 has a date in it (it is crutial),
  but some of them have doubles ('rank'>1) which has a date.
- not every row has a double. And if it doesn't have a date in it, that's ok.

So, I need to find the double with the date if it does exist, and rewrite it to the row with the rank 1 (or delete an incomplete first row)
In the end I need to have a DataFrame with no doubles and as much dates as available.

There's my code with EXTREMELY inefficient iterative loop, but I don't know how to rewrite it with vectorization or .apply() method:

```
def test_func(dataframe):
df = dataframe
df.iloc[0:0]
for i in range(0, dataframe.shape[0]):
    if dataframe.iloc[i]['rank'] == 1:
        temp_row = dataframe.iloc[i]
    
    elif ((dataframe.iloc[i+1]['rank']>1)&
    (pd.isna(dataframe.iloc[i]['date'])
    &(~pd.isna(dataframe.iloc[i+1]['date'])))):
        temp_row = dataframe.iloc[i+1]
    df.loc[i] = temp_row
return df
```

Hope to find some help! From Russia with love xo.

Comment: So your final dataframe should have only Rank 1s ? (either because they already had a date or because it was brought from a Rank > 1) I'm I correct?

Comment: I drop ranks in final df, I use them only to help me sort through doubles, but yeah, the most important is to find and add the date if it is in the row with the rank >1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are grouping by phone, and you are interested in populating missing dates, then you can use backwards fill and group by, which will fill the missing dates with the next available not null date within the group.

```
test_df['date'] = test_df.groupby(['phone'])['date'].apply(lambda x: x.bfill())
```

if you need to populate other missing data, just replace 'date' with the relevant column name